# how to add session in navigate url

Tags: asp.net

Adding a book to the basket and clicking on view basket displays basket fine.
When clicking on the top right hand basket link the screen displays the basket as empty even though a book has been added

Comment: We are going to need to see some code to know what you are doing.  How are items added?  How is the basket page done?  How to you open the links?

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the basket, the you'll have to do a Postback. It seem you allready do that because the item gets added, so i guess the "add" button is in an UpdatePanel. If you put another Updatepanel around the "basket" it should update just fine, or maybe you'll have to add some code to update the basket.